# iPhone App Update and Documents Directory

Tags: iphone, document, app-store

When i update my app I'd like the user to still be able to access their old files. What will the contents of the Documents directory be after updating?

Any tricks or tips shared would be most appreciated on this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content inside `~/Documents` will be same as the old one. See [the *iPhone Application Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW7) on what folders will be kept.