# iPhone Simulating App Update at home before going out in the big bad world

Tags: iphone, document

this is a follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778597/iphone-app-update-and-documents-directory) and the [link given](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW7) it seems that when an app is updated all of the files in the documents directory are copied into the updated apps documents directory and also anything in Library/Preferences. Whats the best way to simulate this for testing purposes?

Just copy the files in ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator etc? or has anyone developped any funky techniques for testing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created .sqlite file in my application's documents folder and created some dummy entries in my database table.

Now just change you code build new application without changing any of the certificate and profile information load the new application.

Now check for the old database table records. It will be definitely preserve under your Document directory in .sqlite file.

This is what i followed when i want to check it for same thing.

If anyone know better way then please feel free to suggest new things.

Jim.