# Does Documents/Inbox get preserved after an update?

Tags: ios7

I know that Documents is preserved after an update, as I know from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778597/iphone-app-update-and-documents-directory).

But is Document/Inbox preserved?
I am assuming so, but the docs say the Inbox is basically read only and mostly in Apple's control.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to simulate an update, and confirmed that the Inbox is preserved (since it's in Documents).

My issue was files in Inbox not appearing after an update, but the actual problem was that the bundle changed so the full path to my file changes.

Simulate an update:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html

Users case on file paths:
[First App Update, User Data Lost (was stored in Documents directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607655/first-app-update-user-data-lost-was-stored-in-documents-directory)